# Virtual Printer. Port Forwarding

Tags: winapi, printing, postscript

this time im trying to develop a "printer application" which allow me to transform that input to a xml and pdf format, some research point me into a print port forwarding solution, like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/PDFWriter.aspx, but at this point i'm stuck, because i don't know how to deal with postscript and how to converted into the desired xml format, if any one have a better idea or can put into the right direction, i will appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided gives you everything you need to generate PDF.  Generating XML is going to require either a postscript-to-XML converter or a print driver that generates XML directly.  Unless you can find existing code that converts postscript to XML, I think the print driver would be the easier approach.  Or simpler still, you can use [this product](http://xmlprinter.com/), which is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: Actually, right now i'm using the product that you mentioned, but we have a couple of requirement which are not accomplished with that product. what about to develop a print driver, where can i start ?

Comment: You need to download and install the WDK (Windows Driver Kit).  You can find it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487463.  Begin with the sample print driver they include. It should be a fairly straightforward matter to modify the sample to output XML in addition to Postscript (which you can use to generate PDF).  However, just be warned that Windows print drivers are non-trivial.  This will be a significant project for you.